# Get the size of the web application

Tags: web-application

I need to get the size of web application using C#. Is there any way we can get the exact size of web application. With powershell it's feasible, but I want to use it in C#

Answer (score 4):

Well, the Web Application itself does not really take up much space! It's just an IIS site on each SharePoint server in the farm. All content is stored in the SharePoint Content Databases. Hence, you can get the size by adding up the size of all attached databases.